# Why does this checkbox not trigger the jquery code onchange? I tried everything, but it is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote some code, and it did not work, so I found some working code, and tried it, but it too, does not work.

Can you tell me why this does not work?

Here is the code I have tried in my header:
1st this one in a script src tag in the head section: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
removed that one and put this one now:
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js

in the head I put this code in a script code tag:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:checkbox").change(function(){
        var the_id= '#' +  this.id + 'f';
        $(the_id).toggle();
        alert('killa-test... popup?');
    });
});
```

After that did not work, I took the code out of the head tag and put it after the form in the HTML in a script tag... so you will see it in the HTML below, it is not repeated... I moved it.

Here is the HTML in the form. I want it to allow them to choose a field they want, and then show() another asking them if they want the field to be required or not.... so I am using the toggle() method as seen above in the jquery.

so here is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="index.cgi" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="lp_setup">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="BackOffice"  /><input type="hidden" name="dothis" value="lp_sys"  /><input type="hidden" name="action" value="doSetup"  /><br />
    <br />
    <div id="webform">
    <br />
        <fieldset style="text-align: left;">
            <legend>Setup Your Landing Page: English - System 1</legend><br />
            <br />
            This is a Landing Page - language: English; Created by one of our distributors, given to use with permission for all of our distributors use. Enjoy it!<br />
            <br />
            Choose the fields You want to Capture on the Landing Page:<br />
            <br />
            First Name <label><input type="checkbox" name="fname" value="1" id="5Jp2bsBb6Dyqryh2Y9Dy7jNd" />Yes - Use This Field</label> <span style="display: none;" id="5Jp2bsBb6Dyqryh2Y9Dy7jNdf"> - <label><input type="checkbox" name="FirstNameError" value="1" />Make this field required?</label></span><br />
            Last Name <label><input type="checkbox" name="lname" value="1" id="LqtEeSrHyNBYK42mPs4DmpDF" />Yes - Use This Field</label> <span style="display: none;" id="LqtEeSrHyNBYK42mPs4DmpDFf"> - <label><input type="checkbox" name="LastNameError" value="1" />Make this field required?</label></span><br />
            Full Name <label><input type="checkbox" name="fullname" value="1" id="qyqxWXLSCmJ9qFZTzF9RE3uL" />Yes - Use This Field</label> <span style="display: none;" id="qyqxWXLSCmJ9qFZTzF9RE3uLf"> - <label><input type="checkbox" name="fullNameError" value="1" />Make this field required?</label></span><br />
            Best Email Address <label><input type="checkbox" name="email" value="1" id="QnvjL9rrEet4gqJ7WXXvL2By" />Yes - Use This Field</label> <span style="display: none;" id="QnvjL9rrEet4gqJ7WXXvL2Byf"> - <label><input type="checkbox" name="emailError" value="1" />Make this field required?</label></span><br />
            Phone Number <label><input type="checkbox" name="phone" value="1" id="L5ZXswQbxrLXNJGeEmh6mtKX" />Yes - Use This Field</label> <span style="display: none;" id="L5ZXswQbxrLXNJGeEmh6mtKXf"> - <label><input type="checkbox" name="phoneError" value="1" />Make this field required?</label></span><br />
            Shipping Address <label><input type="checkbox" name="address" value="1" id="7B55JjLm2xRSQB6M6fbgYN3Y" />Yes - Use This Field</label> <span style="display: none;" id="7B55JjLm2xRSQB6M6fbgYN3Yf"> - <label><input type="checkbox" name="AddressError" value="1" />Make this field required?</label></span><br /><br />
            <br />
        </fieldset><br />
        <br />
    </div><br />
    <br />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input:checkbox").change(function(){
            var the_id= '#' +  this.id + 'f';
            $(the_id).toggle();
            alert('killa');
        });
    });
</script>
</form>
```

Can you help me make this work?

Thank you!
Richard

Comment: Your code works. Look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r8eEm/1/ Problem is probably elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code and it looks alright, so the problem i can think of is the way to include the jQuery library.
Use the tag below and make sure you have it included above your script function, preferably in the < head >  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Test this and tell me if it worked for you.

Comment: that one is in the < head > tag... so I don't know why it is not working...

I tried it in every browser I have, Firefox, IE, Chrome, Safari and Opera, worked in none of them.

Comment: Ok, I copied the source code to my computer, removed all the javascript in there for other programs and tested it and it worked. So there appears to be a conflict... I am going to re-add the other stuff and remove it one at a time until I find the conflict...

Then I will see what the conflict is.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. I had to put the jquery library, below all of the other stuff that the other pages use...

That fixed it. Now it works. Awesome!! Thanks for pointint out it was correct. I thought I did it wrong.

:) appreciate you.